# google charts php "table has no columns"

Tags: php, web-applications, google-visualization

I am working on a chart for a web app. Since this is my first webapp I looked for a quick totorial and  I've found this one: http://mireille.it/example-code-realtime-google-chart-with-mysql-json-ajax/

I changed localhost to this: 
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/threadcountstorage, and have provided my username and password. I've followed the tutorial(copied and pasted and edited the code) and compiled my webapp.

When I load the page all I see is a "Table has no columns" sign and that's it. :(

Bellow is my code for the databaseQuery.php and for the google chart code

php

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect('locahost', 'root', password) or die('Error connecting to server');
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM threadcount');
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
array('label' => 'id', 'type' => 'number'),
array('label' => 'threads', 'type' => 'number')
);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$temp = array();
$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['id']);
$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['threads']);
$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

google charts script

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var json = $.ajax({
                url: 'C:\grails\threadsAPP\grails-app\views\threadcount\databaseQuery.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false
            }).responseText;

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
        var options = {'title':'Total Thread Count',
                        'width':800,
                        'height':600};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Finally, I should mention, how I do not have php installed on my machine, but I do have a php plug in on my IDE

Thank you in advance for any and all help. :)

Comment: that url in the ajax is not going to work, its to the raw file, you need it serve it via the webserver if you want the php code to run

Comment: Does php code even work inside Grails app like that ?

Comment: Not sure if php code works in grails is there a way I can find out?

Comment: Dagon: cab you tell in more detail why the url won't work :)

Comment: @engineerKev, by `C:\grails\threadsAPP\grails-app\views\threadcount\databaseQuery.php` you'll - at best (!) - get the raw PHP in return. Most likely nothing due to Origin Policy

Comment: @davidkonrad First of all thank you :). Also that particular line in the code in most tutorials is  what confuses me a lot since, they all have a php file as their url. So I thought they meant a path to said php file. Now I see I was mistaken, but that still doesn't clear up why for url the tutorials had a php file :/

Comment: I've went ahead and switched  the long path name

C:\grails\threadsAPP\grails-app\views\threadcount\databaseQuery.php
to 
dataBaseQuery.php
and the "Table has no columns" sign is gone, but now there is not graph either :/

Comment: you have `$con = mysql_connect('locahost'` in connection string - loca-host typo